# WordPress: Get ID of custom post type within nested shortcodes

Tags: php, wordpress, nested, shortcode

I'm currently having trouble getting the ID of a custom post type from within a nested shortcode. I'm not sure if this is possible.

Further information to describe my scenario:

- I've created an "Activity" custom post type
- I've created a shortcode called "activity" which displays the
  contents of an activity custom post type based on its ID, this can be
  set using the shortcode attributes
- I've created a shortcode called "textarea" which displays a textarea
  within an acitivty custom post type

The issue that I'm having is that I'm trying to get the "Activity ID" from within the Textarea shortcode but I can't figure a way of doing this.

Please see a diagram via this link to better describe my situation:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/a9bgyjdq9m92qpg/WP-Support---Get-ID-within-Nested-Shortcodes.png?dl=0

**Activity Shortcode Code:**

```
function display_activity($atts, $content = null){

        $a = shortcode_atts( array(
            'id' => null,
        ), $atts ) ;

        if (!is_null($a['id'])){

            $activityId = intval($a['id']);

            if (is_int($activityId) && $activityId > 0){

                $activityObj = get_post($activityId);
                $theTitle = sanitize_post_field( 'post_title', $activityObj->post_title, $activityId, 'display' );
                $theContent = apply_filters('the_content', $activityObj->post_content);

                $html = "<div id='sbusuws-activity-" . $activityId . "' class='sbusuws-activity'>";

                $html .= "<h3 class='sbusuws-activity-title'>" . $theTitle . "</h3>";

                $html .= "<div class='sbusuws-activity-content'>";
                $html .= do_shortcode($theContent);
                $html .= "</div>";

                $html .= "</div>";

                return $html;

            }

        }

    }
```

**Textarea Shortcode:**

```
function display_textarea($atts){

$activityId = ""; // <--- This is the problem
    $textareaId = $activityId . "-sbusuws-activity-textarea";
    $html = "<textarea id='" . $textareaId . "' rows='5' cols='20'>";

    return $html;

}
```

> The idea was to make the textarea shortcode as simple as possible, ie: [textarea]

I'd appreciate any help with this issue.

Thanks!

Comment: Each shortcode works independently. You need to pass ID to `textarea` shortcode.

Comment: @Nilambar Thanks for your response. To stick to my original goal to make the [textarea] shortcode simple for users. I'm looking into a way of dynamically adding the Activity ID as an attribute to the textarea shortcode on Post Save. I'm currently taking a look at: [save post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post) and [get shortcode regex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_shortcode_regex). Hopefully I can get it working. :)

Comment: do you need current post id in the shortcode ?

Comment: @TouqeerShafi Hi Touqeer Shafi, yes, I need the post ID of the current Activity Post.

Comment: then you can do, global $post; $post->ID ?

Comment: @TouqeerShafi yeah, I've tried that but since the Activity post is also (embedded via shortcode) inside a typical WordPress Page, if I try "get_the_ID()" or global $post; $post->ID; I would get the current page ID and not the activity ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this in your `display_activity` method if it works for you ..

```
$theContent = str_replace('[textarea]','[textarea id="'.$activityId.'"]', $theContent); 

$html .= "<div class='sbusuws-activity-content'>";
$html .= do_shortcode($theContent);
$html .= "</div>";
```

Comment: oh wow, I think it's working! I'll test it thoroughly next week, but I think that did the trick! :)